# Norm Inequality in $ C^1([a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to show the following inequality in $C^1([a,b])$:

$$||f||_{\infty}^2\leq \frac{||f||^2_2}{(b-a)}+2||f||_2||f'||_2 $$

where $||f||_{\infty}$ and $||f||_2$ are the $L^{\infty}$ and $L^2$ norms respectively. So far I have tried  to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and then show:

$$||f||_{\infty}^2\leq \frac{||f||^2_2}{(b-a)}+2| \langle  f,f'\rangle  |= \frac{1}{(b-a)} \int_a^bf^2(x)dx+2 |\int_a^bf(x)f'(x) dx|$$

But I am not sure how to prove that the right hand side bounds the sup. I am not aware of any other famous inequality I could use. Note that the Poincare inequality cannot be applied because we are not assuming $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Preferably I am looking for a hint or observation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to the function  $f^2$? You write
$$f^2(x)=f^2(y)+\int_y^x2 f'(t)f(t)\,dt,$$
and then integrate in $y$ over $[a,b]$.

Comment: And make the second summand $f^2(b)-f^2(a)$?

Comment: I added more details